# Can there be multiple parents AND multiple roots for a Directed Acyclic Graph?

Tags: data-structures, directed-acyclic-graphs, operations-research

Can there be multiple parents and/or multiple roots for a DAG?

Answer (score 2):

Nothing in a DAG prevents a node from having more than one parent. Similarly, nothing prevents a DAG from having multiple roots. Thus, yes, you can have these two features in a DAG.

Answer (score 1):

A [DAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) is a graph that flows in one direction, where no element can be a child of itself. **You can still have multiple children and multiple parents for a single node of the graph**.

[image]

> A graph is formed by a collection of vertices and edges, where the
>   vertices are structureless objects that are connected in pairs by
>   edges. In the case of a directed graph, each edge has an orientation,
>   from one vertex to another vertex. A path in a directed graph can be
>   described by a sequence of edges having the property that the ending
>   vertex of each edge in the sequence is the same as the starting vertex
>   of the next edge in the sequence; a path forms a cycle if the starting
>   vertex of its first edge equals the ending vertex of its last edge. **A
>   directed acyclic graph is a directed graph that has no cycles**.

Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph)

At the very minimum, a **directed acyclic graph** must have:

- Nodes: A place to store the data.
- Directed Edges: Arrows that point in one direction (the thing that makes this data structure different)
- **Some great ancestral node with no parents**. (Fun fact: Most ancestry trees are actually DAGs and not actually trees because cousins at some point get married to each other.)
- Leaves: Nodes with no children

Comment: Aren't ALL ancestry trees not actually trees because every node has more than one parent?